# Make columns in an editable html table uneditable

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML table that I created from a pandas dataframe (using `DataFrame.to_html()`).  I want certain columns in the table to be editable so I used `contentEditable` on the table but I am having trouble figuring out how to disable it for certain columns.  I'm using django so the dataframe is converted to an html table in my view and then passed to my html template.

The html/js looks like this:

```
<div class="table-responsive" contentEditable="True">
      {{ table | safe }}
</div>
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete Task</button>
  </div>
</form>
<form class="text-center">
  <a href="/InterfaceApp/Editor" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span> Start a new search</a>
</form>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById("task_table").className = "table table-hover";

    document.getElementById("task_table").tHead.contentEditable = false;
    console.log(document.getElementById("task_table").firstChild.nodeValue);
  });
</script>
```

The python where I make the table looks like this:

```
data = pandas_dataframe_here
table = re.sub(' task_table', '" id="task_table', data.to_html(classes='task_table'))
return render(request,'InterfaceApp/editTasks.html',table)
```

I want the users to be able to edit everything but the 15th and 16th columns of my table.  Is there any way to set `contentEditable` to false for specific columns in the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may cycle through all the row elements and set the 15th & 16th columns' contentEditable property to false.

```
$(function() {
    $("tr").each(function() {
        $(this).find("td:eq(14), td:eq(15)").attr("contentEditable", false);
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you explain how this fixes the problem?

Comment: This simply cycles through each row and sets the contentEditable property on the 15th and 16th column to false.

Comment: It would be better if you edited your answer to include the explanation.

Comment: Fair enough, I just did.

Comment: Works great.  Thanks!